# I'm writing a book called Wilders

Tags: fiction

I am trying to find a name for a creature in my book. it is a shape-shifter, but usually takes the form of a giant badger. it is a bloodthirsty monster, and destroys everything in it's path. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Writers! I'm sorry, but questions looking to generate ideas are not on-topic here here. We've closed this, but please feel free to ask more specific writing questions. You may find our site [tour] helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a particular creature with those attributes, and give it a name of something already existing that is similar, your best bet would be a **Tanuki** (from the Japanese for badger and similar animals), perhaps changing the spelling slightly to fit your purposes.

If you wanted something more original and unique, perhaps a name like Chimeles would fit your tastes? (A portmanteu Chimera and Meles, which is Latin for badger.)

If you wanted it to be an already English word, maybe a word like a Static? A Binate? A Twofold? Simply a Doppelganger? A geminate? A Myriad? Something that refers usually to two, to represent the monochromatic nature of badgers, but can also refer to a large number?

Comment: Doppelganger is already a specific creature in a lot of established stories, so it will not work (as the risk of jarring with the reader is increased). From the sounds of it, it's some kind of were-badger

Answer (score -2):

Names can be funny things I have found... but for some reason this just popped into my mind:
Baragar. Perhaps it will at least help your naming ideas kick in if nothing else :)